# What is the difference between a lambda expression and a predicate in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, predicate

What is the difference between a lambda expression and a predicate in .NET?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A predicate is delegate (function object) that returns a boolean value. [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) can be used to define any anonymous function, which includes predicates, e.g. to express a predicate in the form of a lambda expression:

```
Predicate<int> isEven2 = x => x % 2 == 0;
```

which is functionally equivalent to:

```
Func<int,bool> isEven = x => x % 2 == 0;
```

Comment: A predicate doesn't *have* to be an anonymous function.

Comment: For methods that take a Predicate as an argument (List.FindAll() for example), it would be nice if the compiler recognized Func<T, bool> as a valid Predicate, since they are functionally equivalent. But you can just run it through a lambda like: `var x = MyList.FindAll(i => isEven(i));`

Answer (score 4):

Predicate defines a set of criteria, while lambda expression is an anonymous function. You can use lambda ex. as a predicate, but that doesn't mean they are the same thing.

[Predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx)

[Lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Okay, but what's the difference exactly?