# Can not understand the implementation of until() method in FluentWait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lambda, webdriver

The `until()` method in `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait` is overloaded for `Predicate<T>` and `Function<? super T, V>` interfaces as parameters.

It should take as argument one of the following (which implement the `apply()` method):

- Anonymous class
- Lambda expression
- Method reference

Any lambda that I define as argument for this method throws following error:

The method until(Predicate) is ambiguous for the type WebDriverWait

My Lambda:

```
x -> x.findElement(byLocator).isDisplayed()
```

I assume this will be the case for any lambda, as `apply()` for either Function or Predicate can be implemented by use of these lambda.

**So my question is what is the use of the until method which takes Predicate as parameter?**

Updated:
Removed the first part of question which was answered by @drkthng.

Answer (score 2):

**Answering your first question:**

Have a look at the [Selenium API docs for ExpectedConditon](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html).

I quote:

```
public interface ExpectedCondition<T>
extends com.google.common.base.Function<WebDriver,T>
```

You see, that ExpectedCondition inherited from google's Function interface, thus you can use it as an argument for the until() method.

**As for your second question:**

I don't think you can hand over a lambda just like that. Until method is waiting for a Predicate or Function (as you correctly mentioned).

Regarding the differences between Predicates and lambdas, have a look for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286775/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lambda-expression-and-a-predicate-in-net)

So you can try something like this instead, still using your lambda-expressions:

```
Predicate<WebDriver> myPredicate = x ->x.findElement(By.id("id")).isDisplayed();

WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(myPredicate);
```

Comment: Yes, I never observed, each method in class `ExpectedConditions` return `ExpectedCondition<T>` which `extends Function<T>`. So all my hair-tearing for 1st part of the question was only due to oversight. Thanks for the answer, now for the 2nd part, I am hoping this doesn't turn out to be a fizzler as well.

Comment: was just about to push the second part of my answer, when you commented ;-)

Comment: Thanks again. In general I can pass Lambda directly as well, but in `until()` I am forced to use the reference to the lambda. Which begs the question why overload a method when 1st one (with `Function<T>` as parameter) can achieve same.

Comment: Hey @Husam, what do you mean by "in general I can pass Lambda" ? You mean for other methods that just take Function<? super F, T> as parameter you can hand them over your bare lambda-expression? Do you have an example where it works as you expect.

Comment: Well in Java, lambda expression can be specified only in a context in which a target type is defined. In method's argument, the target type is specified through parameter's type. So yes we can pass lambda directly as method argument. But in `until` this doesn't work, because it is overloaded with with similar type of Functional Interface, hence the ambiguity error. Example that you asked for:

Comment: `String s = (String) squareInWords(i -> String.valueOf(i*i), 2);
 
static CharSequence squareInWords (java.util.function.Function<Integer, ? extends CharSequence> f, Integer n) 
{
    return f.apply(n);
}`

Answer (score 0):

As you said the method `until` is overloaded and the parameters expected are `Predicate<T>` and `Function<? super T, V>`.

Your lambda expression match both signatures, so the call to the method is ambiguous, to solve the ambiguity, there are several options:

Cast the lambda expression to the desired type:

```
until((Predicate<WebDriver>) x -> x.findElement(byLocator).isDisplayed());
```

If you create a variable for the lambda expression, the cast is not needed:

```
Predicate<WebDriver> p = x.findElement(byLocator).isDisplayed();
until(p);
```

If you have a method with this functionality, you can use a method reference:

```
boolean testMethod(WebDriver x) {
    return x.findElement(byLocator).isDisplayed();
} 

until(MyClass::testMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error as your lambda expression match both the predicate and function.

**Consider upgrading the selenium to v3.2.0** -> in which the `FluentWait.until(Predicate<?>)` method is deprecated. And that should make lambdas work properly with Wait instances now.

Answer (score 0):

Below functional interface implementation should resolved issue:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
    wait.pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    wait.withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    wait.until((WebDriver arg0) ->{
    WebElement element = arg0.findElement(By.id("colorVar"));
    String color = element.getAttribute("style");
    System.out.println("The color if the button is " + color);
    if(color.equals("color: red;"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    });
```