# How to adapt to changes in API

Tags: java, design-patterns, lambda, java-8

I have a large project that depends on certain library. One of this library classes exposed the following methods:

```
public void until(final Predicate<T> isTrue)
public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue) {
```

where `Predicate` and `Function` are:

```
com.google.common.base.Predicate<T>
com.google.common.base.Function<? super T, V>
```

In the last version of that library the above has been changed and was refactored by deprecating(removing) the `public void until(final Predicate<T> isTrue)` method and amending the second method as follows:

```
public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue)
```

where Function is now `java.util.function.Function<? super T, V>`.

As far as I understand the above changes has been done to fully support Java 8 features and specifically lambda expressions.

Now to my question. While I can transform all calls to `until` that used the deprecated version of this method to the new structure, I am afraid there are too many places where this method is called. Is there a way I can keep using the old (deprecated) method by maybe re-declaring it elsewhere myself or something of a kind? Any alternative ways to solve this problem are happily accepted.

Comment: Updating Selenium? Do you use the `Predicate` form of `until` much?

Comment: @teppic Please see my question: _While I can transform all calls to `until` that used the deprecated version of this method to the new structure, I am afraid there are too many places where this method is called._

Comment: I'd suggest using IntelliJ's refactoring, but I'm confused at why the API didn't use the Java predicates as well.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach 1. I am on Eclipse 2. Good question 3.See the above comment.

Comment: Looks like the overload was causing people issues.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452685/can-not-understand-the-implementation-of-until-method-in-fluentwait

Comment: @RyanTheLeach that's not the case. Like mentioned in question, the other `until` method that used to accept the `Predicate` is now deprecated and removed.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not saying it's a duplicate, I'm saying the 2 signatures look similar enough, that the linked question is likely one of the reasons why it was removed. Its not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: I’d call that poor design. While it’s immediately understandable what `until(Predicate)` is supposed to do, it’s entirely unclear what `until(Function<? super T,V>)` will do. So the latter method should have been renamed to something better instead deprecated the sane one. That would also fix ambiguity problems with lambda expressions. Still, your refactoring doesn’t need to touch the invocations, but has to substitute `com.google.common.base.Predicate<T>` with `java.util.function.Function<T, V>` to invoke the other method…

Answer (score 2):

**IF** you don't want to change your source code, one possible solution is copy the source code from the library which class have `until(Function)` method in your source code.  and then adding a removed method `until(Predicate)` in your source code. the final code like as below:

```
package ???;//the package of the library which class have `until` method

class ??? {//the class copied from the library which have `until` method
     <T> boolean until(Predicate<T> predicate){
         return until(new Function<T,Boolean>(){
             public Boolean apply(T value){
                return predicate.apply(value);
             }
         });
     }

     <T,R> R until(Function<T,R> function){
        // the source code from the library
     }
     //...  other source code from the library
}
```

the `ClassLoader` will load your class copied from the library only rather than from the library. since the `ClassLoader` uses a delegation model to search the classes / resources and an `AppClassLoader` will always find a class in classpath and then external jars in turn:

> The `ClassLoader` class uses a delegation model to search for *classes* and *resources*. Each instance of `ClassLoader` has an associated **parent class loader**. When requested to find a *class* or *resource*, a `ClassLoader` instance will delegate the search for the *class* or *resource* to its **parent class loader** before attempting to find the class or resource itself. The virtual machine's built-in class loader, called the "**bootstrap class loader**", does not itself have a parent but may serve as the parent of a `ClassLoader` instance.

Another option is write your own `ClassLoader`, and then write a **proxy** to access your library class. this useful when you can't copy the external library class since it depends many its internal classes. for example, let's say you have a library class as below:

```
public class Library<T> {
    private final List<T> items;

    public Library(T... items) {
        this.items = Arrays.asList(items);
    }

    public boolean exists(Function<? super T, Boolean> condition) {
        return items.stream().anyMatch(condition::apply);
    }
}
```

**Then** declaring an interface to matching the library class as below:

```
public interface LibraryAccess<T> {
    boolean exists(Function<? super T, Boolean> condition);
}
```

**Last** write your own class overwrite the library class as below:

```
public class Library<T> {

    private final LibraryAccess<T> library;

    public Library(T... items) {
        // create library from external jars by your own ClassLoader & reflect api
        library = LibraryAccess.newInstance(items);
    }

    public boolean exists(Predicate<? super T> condition) {
        return library.exists(condition::test);
    }

    public boolean exists(Function<? super T, Boolean> condition) {
        return library.exists(condition);
    }
}
```

the whole [source](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/ff26270b4fb1133a6782c68ce0f56b3563f5e369/src/test/java/com/holi/LibraryAccess.java#L14) & [test](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/ff26270b4fb1133a6782c68ce0f56b3563f5e369/src/test/java/test/java/lang/ClassLoaderTest.java#L14-L13) code I have checked in github.

Comment: Thanks, that's a possibility. But in such case I will need to rename the local class that has the copied code which will mean that I still have to change every class where the original class name was mentioned.

Comment: @EugeneS you just to keep the copied class's name same with the library. then you needn't change any source code. e.g: if the library class full name is "x.y.Library" and then your copied class name also is "x.y.Library".